# Restrict Sign In with Google to specific domain

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, openid, google-signin

I was reading the documentation for the new "Sign In with Google" (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference). However, I'm unable to find a way to restrict login to a specific hosted domain i.e. if my college uses Google Workspace accounts with their own domain, I'd like to restrict login to only those accounts.

Note: [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps) is what I used earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict sign-ins to users of your own organization's Cloud Identity or Workspace account, you can [set the OAuth consent screen to **internal**](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#:%7E:text=limit%20authorization%20requests%20to%20members%20of%20the%20organization).

To restrict sign-ins to a set of domains, extend your app to check the [`hd` claim](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#:%7E:text=The%20hosted%20G%20Suite%20domain%20of%20the%20user.%20Provided%20only%20if%20the%20user%20belongs%20to%20a%20hosted%20domain.) in the ID token, which contains:

> The hosted G Suite domain of the user. Provided only if the user belongs to a hosted domain.

Comment: So, if I want to allow a domain without making the app internal, I need to myself check the "hd" parameter?

Comment: Asking because the deprecated version had the check inbuilt

Comment: Yes. It's possible that there are libraries that do that check for you -- but from a protocol perspective, that's what needs to happen.